# How can I get a variable image URL?

Tags: javascript, html, image, url, radio-button

So I got a project here with a couple of radiobuttons. The plan is to be able to select a base, a lining, color and a shading technique. The blue box to the right serves the purpose of giving the customer a live overview of example outcome of the selected parts. I want to place an image there, with a variable URL.

My plan would be to do something like: "https://www.example.com/images/calculator/base+line+color+shading.png"

Where ***base*** is gotten from the base radio input, and could be for example "fullbody"
Where ***line*** is gotten from the line radio input, and could be for example "clean"
Where ***color*** is gotten from the color radio input, and could be for example "colored"
Where ***shading*** is gotten from the shading radio input, and could be for example "ccel"
This would leave us with a variable url of "https://www.example.com/images/calculator/fullbody+clean+colored+ccel.png"

At the same time, I don't want them to have to select all of the inputs to get an overview, if they only select "fullbody", the variable URL should become "https://www.example.com/images/calculator/fullbody.png"

The artist I'm doing this for is rapidly increasing the product base and style choices, and I will be updating it over time, so a solution that is expandable with more options over time would be amazing.

As always, thank you for taking your time to read over, any answers or tips/tricks/hints or pointing in directions is greatly appreciated! Enjoy the weekend folks! <3

[small overview of my project layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxCy2.png)

Comment: This sounds really straight forward... What have you tried?

Comment: I'm new to javascript and need pointers, so sadly is not too straight forward for me. I do not know where to start...

Comment: Start by capturing the `onChange` events for your radio inputs

Comment: Can you use a <select> instead of radio buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data-position="1" is for base group

data-position="2" is for line group

data-position="3" is for color group

data-position="4" is for shade group

..

..

data-position="k" will be for kth value group and so on...

See working example here https://jsfiddle.net/y2khfjwp/40/

```
<div style="width: 50%; float: Left;">
<h2>
Base
</h2>
<input type="radio" name="base" class="main-inputs" data-position="1" value="fullbody" onchange="makeImage(this)"/>Full Body<br>
<input type="radio" name="base" class="main-inputs" data-position="1" value="halfbody" onchange="makeImage(this)"/>Half Body<br>
<input type="radio" name="base" class="main-inputs" data-position="1" value="xyzbody" onchange="makeImage(this)"/>xyz Body<br>
<input type="radio" name="base" class="main-inputs" data-position="1" value="abcbody" onchange="makeImage(this)"/>abc body<br>
<hr>
<h2>
Line
</h2>
<input type="radio" name="line" class="main-inputs" data-position="2" value="clean" onchange="makeImage(this)"/>Clean<br>
<input type="radio" name="line" class="main-inputs" data-position="2" value="clean2" onchange="makeImage(this)"/>Clean2<br>
<input type="radio" name="line" class="main-inputs" data-position="2" value="clean3" onchange="makeImage(this)"/>Clean3<br>
<input type="radio" name="line" class="main-inputs" data-position="2" value="clean4" onchange="makeImage(this)"/>Clean4<br>
<hr>
<h2>
Color
</h2>
<input type="radio" name="color" class="main-inputs" data-position="3" value="colored" onchange="makeImage(this)"/>Colored<br>
<input type="radio" name="color" class="main-inputs" data-position="3" value="colored2" onchange="makeImage(this)"/>Colored2<br>
<input type="radio" name="color" class="main-inputs" data-position="3" value="colored3" onchange="makeImage(this)"/>Colored3<br>
<input type="radio" name="color" class="main-inputs" data-position="3" value="colored4" onchange="makeImage(this)"/>Colored4<br>
<hr>
<h2>
Shade
</h2>
<input type="radio" name="shade" class="main-inputs" data-position="4" value="ccel" onchange="makeImage(this)"/>Ccel<br>
<input type="radio" name="shade" class="main-inputs" data-position="4" value="ccel2" onchange="makeImage(this)"/>Ccel2<br>
<input type="radio" name="shade" class="main-inputs" data-position="4" value="ccel3" onchange="makeImage(this)"/>Ccel3<br>
<input type="radio" name="shade" class="main-inputs" data-position="4" value="ccel4" onchange="makeImage(this)"/>Ccel4<br>
</div>
<div style="width: 50%; float: Right;">
OutPut: <img id="final-output-src" src="Please select Options" /><br><span id="final-output">Please select Options</span>
</div>
<script>
var path = [];
function makeImage(element)
{
  var imagePath = "";
  path[element.getAttribute('data-position')] = element.value;
  imagePath = finalImagePath();
  document.getElementById("final-output-src").src = imagePath;
  document.getElementById("final-output").innerHTML = imagePath;
};
function finalImagePath() {
    var imageSrc = "https://www.example.com/images/calculator/";
    var selections = "";
    for(var i=1 ; i<=path.length ; i++) {
        if(typeof path[i] != 'undefined' && path[i] != '') {
            if(selections == "") {
                selections = selections + path[i];
            } else {
                selections = selections + "+" + path[i];
            }
        }
    }
    if(selections != "") {
        selections = selections + ".png";
        imageSrc = imageSrc + selections;
    }
    return imageSrc;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you really much for this! I will now sit down and study the code and wrap my head around it and learn! :)

Comment: If you found suitable my solution then like and approve above answer @StianM

Comment: Your sollution really helped, and did exactly what I needed. I set as solution.

Another thing, I have set a script up to clear checked status on the line, color and shading radiobuttons when selecting a new base. Is there any way to reset the image so that it sets the new base and clears the line, color and shading from its output?

Comment: Okay you can reset all decedent selections by adding this code:
**Code**
path[element.getAttribute('data-position')] = element.value;
 **replace with:**
if(element.getAttribute('data-position') == '1') { 
      var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("main-inputs");
     for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++){
         if(ele[i].getAttribute('data-position') != '1') {
             ele[i].checked = false;
            }
        }
    path = []; 
   } 
  path[element.getAttribute('data-position')] = element.value;

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/y2khfjwp/48/

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is a solution to generate the image url:

```
const partials = document.querySelectorAll('#partials input');
const fullBody = document.getElementById('fullbody');
const baseUrl = 'some-root-url.com/';
const fileType = '.png';
let imageUrl = baseUrl + 'some-default-url' + fileType;

// Add Event Listeners

fullBody.addEventListener('change', function(){
  let checked = document.querySelectorAll('#partials input:checked');
  // deselect each partial
    for(let i = 0; i < checked.length; i++){
      checked[i].checked = false;
    }
    // Set the imageUrl var to the fullbody
    imageUrl = baseUrl + this.value + fileType;

    // see the imageUrl!
    console.log(imageUrl);
});

for(let i = 0; i < partials.length; i++){
  partials[i].addEventListener('change', function(){
    // uncheck fullBody if checked
    fullBody.checked = false;

    // init the imageUrl
    imageUrl = baseUrl;

    // loop through each checked option and add the value to the imageUrl
    let checked = document.querySelectorAll('#partials input:checked');

    for(let i = 0; i < checked.length; i++){
      imageUrl += checked[i].value;
    }
    // add the file type
    imageUrl += fileType;

    // see the imageUrl!
    console.log(imageUrl)
  });
}
```

And here's the corresponding HTML

```
<div id="partials">
  <label for="base">Base</label><input name="base" type="checkbox" value="base" /><br />
  <label for="line">Line</label><input name="line" type="checkbox" value="line" /><br />
  <label for="color">Color</label><input name="color" type="checkbox" value="color" /><br />
  <label for="Shading">Shading</label><input name="shading" type="checkbox" value="shading" />
</div>

<label for="fullbody">Full Body</label><input name="fullbody" id="fullbody" type="checkbox" value="fullbody" />
```

[And a JSFiddle to demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c53yesqp/49/)

One tip for you as well, you want to use checkboxes not radio, as radio are designed for single choices not multiselect.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for this, however checkboxes is not the way to go for this project, as it is not multiselect, but rather a multi-option. It is true that I would have used checkboxes, should there be options where they could be able to select more than one per type, but not on this. Here its only one per type of a wide selection of products!